# Regex substitution replacement line issue

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to make text in the form of the below text variable print as:

> """Chapter # Chapter title
>
> INTRODUCTION
>
> Top quality text..."""

instead I get:

> """Chapter # Chapter title
>
> X
>
> ..."""

I can't even begin to figure out the error. Where is the X even coming from? This doesn't make sense so I don't know what problem I need to fix.  Does anybody know what the issue is?

```
import re

text = """
...Garbage text prior to start

INTRODUCTION

Top quality text...
"""

file_name = 'Chapter # Chapter title'

def clip_beginning(text):
    '''Removes all text prior to the keyword'''
    beginning_phrase_list = ['INTRODUCTION', 'Starting section 2']
    processed_text = re.sub(rf'(.|\n)*{beginning_phrase_list}', rf'{file_name}\n\1\n', text)
    return processed_text

text = clip_beginning(text)

print(text)
```

Comment: Line 16? rf should be r

Comment: @user3495364, take a look at what I have below. I think it's what you're aiming at. The `rf` is fine, that isn't the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're aiming for? The problem is not with the use of `rf`.

**solution**

```
>>> text = '\n...Garbage text prior to start\n\nINTRODUCTION\n\nTop quality text...\n'
>>> 
>>> beginning_phrase_list = ['INTRODUCTION', 'Starting section 2']
>>> 
>>> file_name = 'Chapter # Chapter title'
>>> 
>>> result = re.sub(rf"^.*?({'|'.join(beginning_phrase_list)})", 
...                 rf"{file_name}\n\n\1", text, flags=re.DOTALL)
>>> 
>>> print(result)
Chapter # Chapter title

INTRODUCTION

Top quality text...

>>> # The expression, when evaluated becomes... 
>>>
>>> becomes = rf"^.*?({'|'.join(beginning_phrase_list)})"
>>> becomes
'^.*?(INTRODUCTION|Starting section 2)'
>>>
```

You were using a grouping in your expression that matched the garbage, then putting it in the substitution string with `\1`. I changed the grouping to match the phrase list. And updated the phrase list match expression to be an OR'ed join of the list.

`flags=re.DOTALL` tells `re.sub()` to match newlines with a dot `.`.

The caret, `^`, tells `re.sub()` to start matching from the beginning of the string - this ensures all the garbage is captured.

Using `rf` in regular expression matches and substitution is fine, and in fact it makes for some very elegant solutions to match and replace operations.

**the mysterious X**

```
>>> # The way it was before...
>>>
>>> evaluates_to = rf'(.|\n)*{beginning_phrase_list}'
>>> evaluates_to
"(.|\\n)*['INTRODUCTION', 'Starting section 2']"
```

Your expression was equivalent to:

```
"(.|\\n)*[ ',2CDINORSTUaceginorst]"
```

Notice the `[...]` match set. By putting the variable `beginning_phrase_list` in your expression raw, you created a match set because of the square braces a list has when stringified.

This is how I converted it into that bizarre looking set:

```
>>> match_set = list( set( str(beginning_phrase_list)[1:-1] ) )
>>> match_set.sort()
>>>
>>> '[' + ''.join(match_set) + ']'
"[ ',2CDINORSTUaceginorst]"
```

What this expression, `"(.|\\n)*[ ',2CDINORSTUaceginorst]"`, will do is hunt for the last character in the target string that matches the match set. Which is the last `t` at the tail end of it: `xt...\n`.

This last `t` is preceded by `x`, which the capture group, `(.|\n)` captures. Parenthesis create a capture group. And that `x` is what `\1` back-reference refers back to in your substitution string, `rf'{file_name}\n\1\n'`.

The capture group and asterisk, `(.|n)*` only create a capture group for one character because the asterisk is not inside the parenthesized expression. The expression alone matches every character preceding the last `t`, but only the last one gets included in the capture group.

And the X is capitalized because.. because *you* capitalized it. It actually comes out as 'x' in the output.

And there you have it... more analysis than you probably anticipated =)

Answer (score -1):

Change...

```
processed_text = re.sub(rf'(.|\n)*{beginning_phrase_list}', rf'{file_name}\n\1\n', text)
```

To...

```
processed_text = re.sub(r'(.|\n)*{beginning_phrase_list}', f'{file_name}\n\1\n', text)
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought I needed to insert the variable as an f-string. I will review this and figure out what the issue was.

Comment: first one r and the second one f but not rf together?  I've updated the answer if that now works for you

Comment: The `rf` is not the problem. `rf` is fine in the expression. There were other problems with the expression @MDR